# How to figure out which plugin contains the desired class?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, plugins, rcp

I want to debug my Java application in Eclipse, but am missing the attacked source. It seems like the .jar does not include any source code.

Next up, I was told to import the needed destination into my workspace as source code from the plugin-view.

So Eclipse tells me the package + class it requires, in this case *org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy*, but although there is a lot of apache plugins in my project, by name, none of them is exactly telling about their content.

I spent a few hours trying to search up the corresponding plugin for my needed class but could not come to any result.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: After selecting name of class 'ClientProxy' in java file, Use the eclipse shortcut ctrl+G .

Comment: I need to find the plugin first since it is not imported as a source project yet? @pikrut

Answer (score 0):

Open the Preferences and go to 'Plug-in Development'.

Select the 'Include all plug-ins from target in Java search' check box.

Once this is done things like 'Navigate > Open Type' will search all the plug-ins to find classes.

When you have opened a class in an editor you can use 'Navigate > Show In > Package Explorer' to show the location of the class. This will show you the plug-in.

Comment: This will just result in source not found. That's what I wanted to resolve.

Comment: Your question title says find out which plugin it is in. This will find the plugin, not all plugins come with source.

Comment: Ye but I'm talking about external plugins which I would have to import first as source project to see the code.